# bmp image shows background pixels - how to correct

Tags: bmp

SAP forces me to upload images in BMP format. However, even though these are uploaded with white backgrounds, SAP prints them with pixelated backgrounds.
Is it possible to correct this problem, that is, to have a white or transparent background for the image, while maintaining the BMP format? If yes, how? What is the path, if any, to follow?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C4Qf.jpg)

thank you

These are the options we use and the program used to try to convert the image is convert.exe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQUjT.png)

However, the background is still printed out